# Restricting a signal handler to catch signals from only that particular file where it is defined

Tags: c, linux, signals

Hi 
I have a signal handler defined in one file, from where the signal is generated. I have defined a "static struct sigaction" to define a signal handler which is non-static.

We know using "static" we can also put scope limitation to one single file, so using this technique can we restrict the signal handler to catch signals from only the file in which it is defined?

My "file" - File1, which is linked with other file - File2, File2 can generate signals, which should not be caught by File1 handler. So can i achieve this, if i put "static struct sigaction" in File1?

```
enter code here
File1.c

static struct sigaction;
void sigHandler(int sig); // also a handler for SIG_NO but should catch signals generated for only File1.c (sig handler is non-static)

File2.c
kill(getpid(), SIG_NO)

File1.c and File2.c are linked together.
```

Comment: Can we have some code to look at please?

Comment: It's still on the design phase, so no code we have. But i can give some briefings, will edit above and put it.

Comment: May be you should try adding, say handler for SIGINT, use `signal(SIGINT, handler)` at the beginning of that file(should be defined within a function) and before returning from that function use `signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really doesn't matter where you declare / define the handler. If you get to install the handler, it handles ALL the signals of that type received by the process.

So, no matter the scope and linkage of your identifiers, once you install the handler it handles everything.

Comment: Then what is the use of "static", if i declare a variable as static, it should be scope limited to that file?

Comment: That is not what `static` is for.

Comment: I mean that is an additional use of static (scope limitation to files), please check.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly.

The information about what specific file generated a given segment of code is not part of the executable (except for debug information, but that is not used or parsed by the kernel).

You'll need to implement some logic in your application and in the signal handler if the signal is only to be acted upon in some situations.

(Or re-think your application design and implement two separate processes.)

Comment: But i have put the `sigaction` as static.

Comment: that's irrelevant. once all your files are linked into the executable,  there is no more information as to what was in which source file. (except for debugging information if any, which is not used by the kernel).*

Comment: So you say, scope limitation to variables in one single file can't be achieved using static?

Comment: scope limitation is a compile-time limitation. at runtime, there is no such thing as "file scope" - there are no "files" in the executable.

Comment: So is there any way, so that i can limit the handler to catch signals generated for only that particular file?

Comment: @kingsmasher1  In every function defined in the file, set the signal disposition to your handler when the function starts and set it back to the default (or the old handler) when the function ends.  In other words, "no".